# aiomysql.create_pool and sqlalchemy

Tags: python

how should I use aiomysql.create_pool and sqlalchemy in Python,  That would seem to go wrong

```py
async def pg_context(app):
    conf = app['config']['mysql']
    # engine = await aiomysql.sa.create_engine(
    #     db=conf['database'],
    #     user=conf['username'],
    #     password=conf['password'],
    #     host=conf['host'],
    #     port=conf['port'],
    # )
    engine = await create_pool(
        db=conf['database'],
        user=conf['username'],
        password=conf['password'],
        host=conf['host'],
        port=conf['port'],
    )
    app['db'] = engine

    yield

    app['db'].close()
    await app['db'].wait_closed()
```

```py
async def index(request):
    """

    :param request:
    :return:
    """
    async with request.app['db'].acquire() as conn:
        # cursor = await conn.execute(user.select())

        cursor = await conn.cursor()
        await cursor.execute(user.select())

        records = await cursor.fetchall()
        questions = [dict(q) for q in records]
        return web.Response(text=str(questions))
```

The result is that

```py
    chunk_size = min(MAX_PACKET_LEN, len(sql) + 1)  # +1 is for command
TypeError: object of type 'Select' has no len()
```

I don't know what to do with it except use str(), right

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

emmm, I have an easy way to solve this problem,

```py
    async with request.app['db'].acquire() as conn:
        # cursor = await conn.execute(user.select())

        cursor = await conn.cursor()

        struct = str(user.select()).replace('\n', ' ').replace('"', '')
        await cursor.execute(struct)

        records = await cursor.fetchall()
        print(records)
        return web.Response(text='test')
```

This uses strings to slow down the code, but saves database connection and disconnection costs by using database connection pooling.